# hough ellipse not detecting the ellipse

Tags: python, computer-vision, scikit-image, ellipse, hough-transform

I made several attempts with the threshold to detect the GCP´S from my aerial image ..so here I have input the approximate location of the GCP and then took that part (GCP center + w) from the aerial image and then applied canny operator, hough ellipse ..can you please suggest if I have to do some pre-processing or try further to change the threshold to detect the ellipse

markers_projections.txt contains

DJI_0004,point 2,2974.33642578125,901.3115234375

input image link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zud4PZDhU8552Vv3jypIG5WEzFEffYX4/view?usp=sharing

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from IPython import get_ipython
from resizeimage import resizeimage

from skimage import data, color, img_as_ubyte
from skimage.feature import canny
from skimage.transform import hough_ellipse
from skimage.draw import ellipse_perimeter


get_ipython().magic('clear')
w = 60  #window size
i = 0
counter = []



path_input = "C:\\Users\\D29607\\Downloads\\photos-20191230T160410Z-001\\photos\\markers_projections.txt"
path_output = "C:\\Users\\D29607\\Downloads\\photos-20191230T160410Z-001\\photos\\markers_projections_corrected_2.txt"
f1 = open(path_input,'r')
f2 = open(path_output,'w')

def auto_canny(image, sigma=2.5):
    # compute the median of the single channel pixel intensities
    v = np.median(image)

    # apply automatic Canny edge detection using the computed median
    lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
    upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))
    edged = cv2.Canny(image, lower, upper)

    # return the edged image
    return edged

for line in f1:

    print('Start processing')
    print(line)
    a = line.split(',')
#       print(line)
    fname = "./flight/rgb/"+a[0]+'.jpg'
    print(fname)
    x = np.int(float(a[2]))
    y = np.int(float(a[3]))

    img = cv2.imread(fname,-1)
#    img_enhanced = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img,w,w,w,w,cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE) # padding to enlarge the images

    sub = img[y-w:y+w+1,x-w:x+w+1]
    image_gray = color.rgb2gray(sub)

    edges = canny(image_gray, sigma=2.0,low_threshold=0.515, high_threshold=0.59)
#        
    plt.imshow(edges)  

#    print('Finished ')   
#        
    result = hough_ellipse(edges,accuracy=14, threshold=50,
                        min_size=10, max_size=25)
####                        
    print(result) 
    result.sort(order='accumulator')
###        
###        print(result)
    for i in result:
##            
        best = list(i)
#####        print(best)
#        print(best)
        yc, xc, a, b = [int(round(k)) for k in best[1:5]]
        orientation = best[5]
####
##### Draw the ellipse on the original image
        cy, cx = ellipse_perimeter(yc, xc, a, b, orientation)
        sub[cy, cx] = (0, 0, 255)
#### Draw the edge (white) and the resulting ellipse (red)
        edges = color.gray2rgb(img_as_ubyte(edges))
        edges[cy, cx] = (250, 0, 0)
###
        fig2, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=1, figsize=(8, 4),
                                sharex=True, sharey=True)
####
        ax1.set_title('Original picture')
        ax1.imshow(sub)
###
        ax2.set_title('Edge (white) and result (red)')
        ax2.imshow(edges)
###
    plt.show()
###
f1.close()
f2.close()
#####        
####
```

Please click these links to check my results
[Result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xekTA.png) 
[result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbsDX.png)

Comment: You should share the example input images too.

Comment: @CrisLuengo please check the post now

Answer (score 0):

i have the some results can any one suggest if i can apply hough ellipse for this now?[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6e4Q.png)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython import get_ipython
from skimage import data, color, img_as_ubyte
from skimage.feature import canny
from skimage.transform import hough_ellipse
from skimage.draw import ellipse_perimeter


get_ipython().magic('clear')

w = 80  #window size
i = 0
counter = []

path_input = "C:\\Users\\Darshan Savanur\\Downloads\\markers.txt"
path_output = "C:\\Users\\Darshan Savanur\\Downloads\\markers_projections_corrected_2.txt"
f1 = open(path_input,'r')
f2 = open(path_output,'w')
for line in f1:

    if i >-1:
        a = line.split(',')
        print(a[0])
        fname = "./project/20191024/flight/rgb/"+a[0]+'.jpg'
        x = np.int(float(a[2]))+w
        y = np.int(float(a[3]))+w

        img_ = cv2.imread(fname,-1)
        img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img_,w,w,w,w,cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE) # padding to enlarge the images

        sub = img[y-w:y+w+1,x-w:x+w+1]
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(sub, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#        plt.imshow(gray)

#        sigma = 0.3
#        v = np.median(gray)
#
#---- apply automatic Canny edge detection using the computed median----
#        lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
#        upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))
#        edged2 = cv2.Canny(gray, lower, upper)

        edged = canny(gray, sigma=2.0,
              low_threshold=0.55, high_threshold=0.8)
        edged = edged.astype(np.uint8)  #convert to an unsigned byte
        edged*=255
#        

        ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(edged, 127, 255, 0)
        contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
#        
        for c in contours:
#                # if the contour is not sufficiently large, ignore it
                if cv2.contourArea(c) < 150 :
                    continue
                orig = sub.copy()

                cv2.drawContours(orig, c, -1, (255, 255, 0), 3)
#
#                # show the output image
                cv2.imshow("Image", orig)
                cv2.waitKey(0)
```